# Problema de redirecionamento no Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular

Estou com um problema no redirecionamento do Angular

Segue abaixo o arquivo cadastro-cliente.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { debounceTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-cadastro-clientes',
  templateUrl: './cadastro-clientes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cadastro-clientes.component.css']
})
export class CadastroClientesComponent implements OnInit {
  formCadastro;
  valoresForm: Object;
  conversao;
  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router
    ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formCadastro = this.fb.group({
      data: [''],
      horario: [],
      alfanumerico: [],
      numero: [],
      texto: []
    });
    console.log(this.valoresForm);
    this.formCadastro.valueChanges.pipe(
      debounceTime(1000))
      .subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.valoresForm = res;
      });
  }
  
  objetoCadastro() {
    console.log(this.formCadastro.controls);
    this.conversao = JSON.stringify(this.valoresForm);
    localStorage.setItem('objetoCadastro', this.conversao);
    this.router.navigate(['/cadastro-clientes']);

  }
  verificaCadastro() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (localStorage.getItem('cadastro')) {
        // TODO REDIRECIIONAR PARA PAGINA DE CADASTRO CONCLUIDO
        this.router.navigate(['']);
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }, 200);
}
}
```

Quero que após enviar os dados do formulário, ele retorne para a página incial, ou qualquer outra. Nenhuma está funcionando.

E a propósito, os dados estão sendo enviados:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se alguém puder me auxiliar...

Comment: Olá Weslley, tente usar o routerlink, acredito que deva funcionar. https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink